React State not saving at all
In the auth and login function, the data returned is correct, but when I save it to state, it just disappears
export const useAuth = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    return {
        user,
        async login({mail, password, stayLoggedIn}) {
            const res = await logIn({mail, password, stayLoggedIn})
            console.log(res.data)
            if(res.status===200) setUser(res.data)
            return res;
        },
        async auth() {
            try {
                const res = await autoLogin();
                console.log(res.data) // correct data
                setUser(res.data)
                console.log(user) // null
                return res;
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
        },
        async logout() {
            setUser(false)
        }
    }
}

Expected result was to have the user data saved to state, then pass it as context to the rest of the app.

User is declared as a const to hint at the fact that the variable cannot/will not be modified, unless the component is rebuilt (that’s what a re render does)

setState in React is async, if you want to use the value after an update, you need to use :
useEffect(() => {
   console.log(user);
}, [user]));

